# Foldback current limiting in RC servo application

Tags: batteries, schematics, current-limiting, servo, remote-control

**Background:** A 7.4V 2Ah battery (LP-E6 from Canon) powers our system (camera/laser mounted on a one-axi gimbal). The gimbal motor is an RC servo (HPS AA701 from Futaba) connected directly to the battery. The gimbal is mounted on a carbon fiber telescopic pole.

**Issue:** We chose this servo because it is shockproof and very robust. But when the operator forces the gimbal (on a obstcale for instance), the current can quickly rise up to 5A (while 500mA at idle) for several seconds. We would like to limit the current drawn to 2-3A (thus limiting torque), in order to protect the battery and to prevent the system from shutting down (because of the voltage drop in the battery).

**Solution:** I think a foldback current limiter could do the trick by limiting the current without shutting down the whole system. I don't know if it is a good idea or not. I do not have much experience in electronics.

**Source:** I saw this [good website](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/power-supply-electronics/current-limiter-circuit.php) about current limiting but since there is no voltage regulator to power the servo, I don't know if it is a good solution. There is maybe an IC that can do the whole job.

Comment: Concentrate on asking a question and providing sufficient detail so that someone can think about the technicalities involved in adding a current limiter. You should also think about what happens if fold-back current limiting is added and how you might get the system to reset from a stall situation.

Comment: One could use also an automatic step-up step-down with current limiting ... to check.